# Update query after the selected records from a Select Query

Tags: database, apache-camel

I have to select some rows from table, send the result to a queue and then the same records as 'Sent' in the DB.
This how I am trying to do this but not sure how to pass a column value to the **where** clause of the update query for the each record of the select query.

```
<route> 
 <from uri="timer://kickoff?period=10000"/>
     <setBody>
       <constant>select top 10 * from tableName</constant>
     </setBody>
 <to uri="jdbc:test"/>
 <multicast>
        <to uri="activemq:queue:TESTQUEUE"/>
        <setBody>
            <constant>update tableName set status='Sent' where primaryKey= ${primaryKey}</constant>
        </setBody>
    <to uri="jdbc:test"/>
 </multicast>
</route>
```

Will this route will run for all 10 records?

If it is not possible with JDBC/SQL component then how to achieve it with Hibernate component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a query using Camel JDBC, you will get back an ArrayList of HashMaps.  See the camel documentation here:

http://camel.apache.org/jdbc.html

"The result is returned in the OUT body as an ArrayList>. The List object contains the list of rows and the Map objects contain each row with the String key as the column name."

You will need to setup a spring bean to process this body.  You can extract your primary key from the arraylist in the spring bean and set a header.  From there you can use the splitter to process all the rows:

http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html